# How can I match around characters in python regex

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a String like

`abc{123}hij`

And i want to remove all the digits inside of the curly braces. To match them, I would use

`\{(\d+)\}`, but i think looking from beginning to { and from } to end is easier.

`(.+?\{)*(\}.+)*` works, but it matches a few null matches. not a regex expert so i am not entirely sure what is happening here, but I think i have to exchange the * for something.

Thanks!

edit:

input:
xxx{123}xxx

expected output/match:
xxx{}xxx

Comment: It seems `\d+(?=[^{}]*})` should be enough. Else, you can use `re.sub(r'{[^{}]*}', lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x.group() if not i.isdigit()]), text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that but it results in no matches.

Comment: What are your *actual* inputs that don't match. Saying "resulted in no matches" doesn't help us much if we don't know what you're actually doing.

Comment: What is the exact code you are using to test? Please update the question.

Comment: Remove all the digts or letters?

Comment: I am sorry @WiktorStribiżew I made a mistake in my question, there are supposed to be numbers inside of the {}. all numbers inside of {} should be removed

Comment: Match `(?<={)\d+(?=})` and replace with a empty string. https://regex101.com/r/ms9gXE/1

Comment: Then just use `re.sub(r'{\d+}', '{}', text)`

Comment: Did it finally work? I see the question status has not changed, do you still need more help with this?

Comment: Witam wiktor! I was hoping to find a solution, that matches text without having to manually add the characters back in, but i think your solution is the easiest one that does what I need. Forgot to check back here, thanks for the solution, just accepted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'{\d+}', '{}', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KvrKlv/1).

The `{\d+}` regex matches `{`, one or more digits, and then a `}` char. Since the curly braces are hard-coded in the pattern, it is easy to use them in the replacement pattern.

Here are some variations of the same solution:

```py
re.sub(r'({)\d+(})', r'\1\2', text)
re.sub(r'(?<={)\d+(?=})', '', text)
```

**Bonus**: if you need to remove digits from between two curly braces, you can use

```py
re.sub(r'{[^{}]*}', lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x.group() if not i.isdigit()]), text)
```

Here, `{[^{}]*}` matches any substrings between the curly braces and `lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x.group() if not i.isdigit()])` removes all digits.

If you know the curly braces in your strings are paired and not nested, you can use

```
re.sub(r'\d+(?=[^{}]*})', '', text)
```

The `\d+(?=[^{}]*})` regex matches one or more digits followed with zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` then followed with `}`.